# python 3.5.2/Django app: HTTPS request code works from computer A, fails on computer B

Tags: python, django

**SEE UPDATE AT BOTTOM:**

python 3.5.2:

A simply https request works on computer A.
Fails on computer B.

Same codebase. Identical 100%. Python 3.5.2 on both. Same home network/internet connection used. Same OS (OS X El Capitan). OpenSSL version identical in both machines: 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

Exception is:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
>   (_ssl.c:645)

Obviously this is not code. is there something environmental with the python installation or the machine it self.

Does anyone have a clue what could have gone wrong?

**UPDATE:**

following advice here I imported ssl into the python shell and checked its version. it would seem that although the terminal command line openssl executable on both machines is identical -0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016 the python shell response is different on both computers.

- The one that works shows: OpenSSL OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016
- The one that does not work shows: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

I assume upgrading 0.9.8 to 1.0.2 would make the difference.

Comment: What versions of openssl? i.e what does `openssl version` output from the bash for each system?

Comment: identical in both machines OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

Comment: How was python installed on both machines?

Comment: The UI installer  downloaded from here :https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/

Comment: Run import ssl  SSL.OPENSSL_VERSION from a python shell on both

Comment: Use `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`

Comment: `import ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'; 'ssl' is not a package`

Comment: same when I replace OPENSSL_VERSION with the actual version

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I did do this on a separate line. the stackoverflow comments editor does not permit newlines.

Comment: import ssl then after you hit return enter `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`

Comment: ok. after importing ssl, I `print (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)` and get `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016` on the machine it doesn't work on.... however, on the one it DOES work on, I get `OpenSSL 1.0.2h 2 may 2016`.

Comment: which is strange because the command line openssl is the same version in both machine.  So, on the machine that works, I have a better openSSL python package. I guess that could be it?

Comment: Yes but one of the installations is still referencing an older install of openssl, how did you install openssl?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this. If yo'd write your response as an answer I'll credit you for it.

Comment: I did not explicitly install it - i believe it is a dependency in one of the modules I'm importing. IS there a way for force `pip` to upgrade the ssl module to the required version ?

Comment: The issue is what your python version was compiled against, I don't use osx but reinstalling from source should sort out the issue.

Comment: You mean re-install python from source?

Comment: yes, you could use https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv, I use it for multiple python installs, it should compile using the new version of openssl

Comment: Building python3 worked. Its now built with openssl 1.0.2 and my https request (TLS 1.2) works as expected, as it does on the other machine. If you write something as an answer, I'll be able to credit you for the solution and close this item.